# Excel: change data source with macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, csv

I'm using a CSV file (generated by a thing party program) as an external datasource, and I'd like to change its path from a macro... How can I do that ?

Another acceptable answer to my problem would be a way to specify a path relative to the excel file—haven't found how—given that in my case, both the csv and the xls are in the same directory.

Comment: You can reference external data in a formula, is that what you're looking to do? You can reference the absolute path to a file. You're looking to reference a relative path to a file? [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/about-linking-to-another-workbook-or-program-HP005198424.aspx) here you can see how to reference both absolutely and relatively

Comment: I'm neither referencing an external _Excel_ file, neither using a formula (just importing the data, using the data Tab.

Comment: So you want a macro to import the data from the csv?

Comment: No, not really. I did that with the Excel native function: `Data>From text>...` and configured my CSV and all. What I want is to be able to change just _the path of the file_ of the **already existing** datasource.

Comment: Which version of excel are you using? 
Also can't you go to `data -> existing connections -> select connection -> right click edit connection properties -> definition tab -> browse`
This would enable you to change it, are you looking to automate that process such that you can type in which one you want into say, cell A1 and it would run the macro in reference to what you entered?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2010 on Windows and Excel 2011 on MacOS. And yes the point of the macro I need, is to automate the process you're describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Import()
    Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = "TEXT;C:\directory\" & Cells(1, 1).Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=FilePath, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "Book1"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

This will create a new sheet with the data when you put the file (book3.csv for instance) in sheet1 A1; you change C:\directory to the directory in which your input exists and you can change the range of output in line 5 "Range"

Additionally, line 3 "Cells(1,1) indicates the input cell, so you can change that from Sheet1 A1 if you'd like. You need to indicate the file extension in the reference cell otherwise it won't know what file to import. Just run this macro and you'll get a new sheet with the target data. If you need a new workbook or for it to insert it into an existing sheet, let me know.

Also, if you look at the properties this is a comma delimited file, you can change that, or just record your own macro (developer tab -> record macro) and insert the FilePath type commands at the top and change the connection command

Comment: Ok, great! Can't check that now, I'll look into it later on. Thanks.